# All roots to one variable transcendental equation

Tags: transcendental-numbers, transcendental-equations, transcendental-functions

How to find all possible roots for one variable transcendental equation?
The equation is as follows:
$\cosh(x)\cos(x)+1=0$

How should I solve the above equation if it has two variables?
$\cosh(x)\cos(y)+1=0$

Comment: There is an infinite number of roots and numerical methods would be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a real root between $n \pi$ and $(n+1) \pi$ for every integer $n$.  For large $n$, writing $x = (n+1/2) \pi + t$, the equation
becomes $$\sin(t) = \frac{(-1)^n}{\cosh(t + (n+1/2) \pi)}$$
No closed form, but we can approximate it.  Let $\tau = e^{-(n+1/2) \pi}$, so we can expand
$$ \sin(t) \approx
2 (-1)^n \left( \tau e^{-t} -  \tau^3 e^{-3t} +  \tau^5 e^{-5t} + \ldots \right)$$
and expand the solution in an asymptotic series:

$$t = (-1)^n \left( 2 \tau - 4 \tau^2 + \frac{34}{3} \tau^3 - \frac{113}{3} \tau^4 + \ldots\right) $$

Answer (score 0):

In this question, there are two problems :

- the equation is  transcendental which means that, more than likely, numerical methods would be required.
- because of the cosine, there will be an infinite number of roots.

Moreover, if $x$ is a root, $-x$ will be another one.

PLotting the function over a given range will give an idea about the root locations and using a "reasonable" guess $x_0$ for a specific root, Newton method will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ In this specific case $$f(x)=\cos (x) \cosh (x)+1$$ $$f'(x)=\cos (x) \sinh (x)-\sin (x) \cosh (x)$$

For illustration purposes, let us consider the first roots
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 2 \\
 1 & 1.88527 \\
 2 & 1.87518 \\
 3 & 1.87510 
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 5 \\
 1 & 4.76087 \\
 2 & 4.69825 \\
 3 & 4.69411 \\
 4 & 4.69409 
 \end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 8 \\
 1 & 7.87238 \\
 2 & 7.85506 \\
 3 & 7.85476 
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 11 \\
 1 & 10.9956 \\
 2 & 10.9955 
 \end{array}
\right)$$

As you can notice, more or less, the next root is more or less equal to the previous root plus $\pi$.

Naming $a_n$ the $n^{th}$ root,we can easily approximate the next one using a single step of Newton method writing $$0=f(a_{n+1})\approx f(a_n+\pi)+(a_{n+1}-a_n-\pi)f'(a_n+\pi)\implies a_{n+1}\approx$$